# jquery multiple links text replacement from id in target href page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm experimenting with jquery, and thought it would be comfortable to have my links get their content from their source. I'm not really sure it's possible though.

```
<a href="page1.html" >pagetitle</a>
<a href="page2.html" >pagetitle</a>
```

What I want to achieve is replace "pagetitle" with text from #title id, ex : "My page 1" from target, for every link, on pageload.

Source element in the pages :

```
<h1 id="title">My page 1</h1>
```

Desired output :

```
<a href="page1.html" >My page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" >My page 2</a>
```

I tried various solutions but I can't achieve the desired behavior.
If impossible with jquery, telling me will also help ! Thanks for your time.

Edit : I tried some basic lines as follow :

This works, but of course with only one page so obviously every title is the same.

```
$( 'a' ).load( 'page1.html .title' ).text();
```

These won't work, maybe I'm a bit clumsy !

```
$( 'a' ).load( 'a.attr("href") .title' ).text();

var distantcontent = $('a.attr("href")');
$( 'a' ).load( 'distantcontent .title' ).text();
```

Comment: If those href's are on same origin as in the example then you can get the target content via jquery or js (ajax) and extract what you need. If the target page is on another domain, subdomain or protocol then you'll have cross-site scripting limitations and would need to do it server side. Show us what you tried!

Comment: It is from same origin !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... It works with the test pages I made.

See comments in code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Get all the href (If there is!)
  var hrefArray = [];
  $("a").each(function(){
    if( $(this).attr("href") !="#" && $(this).attr("href") != "undefined" ){
      hrefArray.push( $(this).attr("href") );
    }
  });

  var i = 0;
  function getTitles(href, i){
    $.ajax({
      url: href,
      success: function(response){
        // Stringify the result
        var responseString = response.toString();

        // Get the index of the title tag
        var titleTagIndex = responseString.indexOf("<title>");

        // If the title tag IS found
        if(titleTagIndex != -1){

          // Find the index of the title closing tag
          var titleClosingTagIndex = responseString.indexOf("</title>");

          // Get the sub-string between the two indexes we found.
          title = responseString.substr(titleTagIndex+7,titleClosingTagIndex-(titleTagIndex+7));
          console.log("Title found: "+title);

          // Replace the link text.
          $("a").eq(i).text(title);
        }

        // Get the next title
        i++;
        if(i<hrefArray.length){
          getTitles(hrefArray[i], i);
        }
      },
      error: function(request, status, error){
        console.log(error);
      }
    })
  }

  // Get the first title
  getTitles(hrefArray[i], i);
});
```

Now, the titles are requested one by one using ajax.
You WILL notice the delay for it to populate the titles on load.

If you also have external links on your page, instead of `$("a")`, use a class to target your "same domain" links... Because the ajax wil fail on external links and just stop the looping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the individual  elements.  Something like this:

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  u = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log('$(this).load(' + u + ' .title)');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="page1.html">My page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html">My page 2</a>
```